# Problem on speed and frame numbers settings of cylinder stimulus in matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation

I have tried to make rotating cylinder stimulus in matlab. In my setting, my cylinder stimulus should move the length of stepD(=635) forward in 60 frames during 1.433 seconds.

However, when all 3 scripts below runs, it moves more than the stepD length in 1.433 seconds on my eyes. So it moves so faster than I expected. I think that problem is in frame setting. I am new to matlab. If anyone can solve this problem, please help me...ㅠㅠ

Below are three code files for creating cylinder stimulation that I use. To make a stimulus, after saving the three, they run in sequence. Thank you.

*first code file

```
clear;
makeCyl = 1;

%% parameters

W = 100; %width
ndot = 400;
NumFrames = 60;
stepD = 635;  % ie the half perimeter of the cylinder
cylR = stepD/pi;       %guarantee the cylinder aprroaches with the same distance per 180 degree as the figure walks a step

%% cylinder
if makeCyl
    
    backCol=0.9;
    dotx = sin((rand(1,ndot)-0.5)*pi)* W/2; %dots are more concentrated on the two boundaries after ttransformed to sin, more natural than sqrt
    dotc = ones(1, ndot);
    angs = 2*pi* rand(1,ndot);
    angpf = 2*pi/NumFrames;  %angle per frame
    
    Cylin = NaN(NumFrames*3,ndot);  %keep it the same format as the mov file
    dotC = cell(NumFrames,1);
    for zz = 1:NumFrames
        
        Cylin(zz*3-2,:) = dotx;
        Cylin(zz*3-1,:) = cylR*cos(angs);
        Cylin(zz*3,:) = cylR*sin(angs);  % all dots are in the same depth so that it won'd contain perspective cue when drawn by moglDrawDots3D
        angs = angs-angpf;
        dotc = ones(1, ndot);
        dotc(:, mod(angs,2*pi)<=pi) = backCol;
        dotC{zz}= [1;1;1]*dotc;
    end
    
    save('Cylin_aaa','Cylin' ,'ndot');
end
```

*Second code file

```
function [rotmat] = RotationMatrix(phi,axis)
% Usage [rotmat] = RotationMatrix(phi,axis)
% 
% Gives a 3D rotation matrix
% phi  =  the angle (in rad) of rotation
% axis =  the axis around which the rotation is performed
%
% JvB, Sept 2011

    rotmat = ...
    [ cos(phi)+axis(1)^2*(1-cos(phi))                   axis(1)*axis(2)*(1-cos(phi))-axis(3)*sin(phi)       axis(1)*axis(3)*(1-cos(phi))+axis(2)*sin(phi)   ;...
      axis(2)*axis(1)*(1-cos(phi))+axis(3)*sin(phi)     cos(phi)+axis(2)^2*(1-cos(phi))                     axis(2)*axis(3)*(1-cos(phi))-axis(1)*sin(phi)   ;...
      axis(3)*axis(1)*(1-cos(phi))-axis(2)*sin(phi)     axis(3)*axis(2)*(1-cos(phi))+axis(1)*sin(phi)       cos(phi)+axis(3)^2*(1-cos(phi))     ];
end
```

*third code file

```
InitializeMatlabOpenGL;
load('Cylin_aaa.mat')
nFrames = 60;
fr = 1;
InitializeMatlabOpenGL; % open GL reset, moglDrawDots3D Required for function execution
%Screen('Preference', 'SkipSyncTests', 1);
Screen('Preference', 'SkipSyncTests', 1) % Skip sync test for testing
whichScreen = max(Screen('Screens'));
[w, screenRect] = Screen('OpenWindow', whichScreen,[0 0 0],[]); % small screen output
ScreenCenter = [screenRect(3)/2 screenRect(4)/2];
commandwindow;



while fr <= 86
    
    thefr = fr;
    while thefr > nFrames; thefr =thefr-nFrames; end

    disp(thefr); % Check frame progress
    this_xyz =  Cylin(thefr*3-2:thefr*3,:);
    
    % to change the view angle:
    angle = -3/4;
    this_xyz = RotationMatrix(angle,[0 1 0]) * this_xyz;
    % RotationMatrix apply a rotation in either x, y, z dimension. You can
    % try to change to [0 0 1] to rotate in other dimension
    
    Screen('DrawDots',w, this_xyz(1:2,:),[],[255 255 255],ScreenCenter, 0);
%     moglDrawDots3D(w, this_xyz, 1, [1 1 1]); %
    
    Screen('Flip',w);
    %WaitSecs(0.05); % To see the dot move slowly
    
    fr = fr +1;
end
sca;
```